# How do I make a post request in node using parse server?

Tags: node.js, http-post, httprequest, parse-server

I am doing some work with an api, and I need to make a post request to my parse server, but I get the error `error:{unauthorized access}`, I am pretty sure it is because of the keys, but I am unsure. I am using postman to see if I can make a request to the app.post function, but I am getting the above error. I am making a request to `https://xxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/parse/index/testing

```
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.status(200).send('I dream of being a website.  Please star the parse-  server repo on GitHub!');
});


app.post('/testing', twilio.webhook({ validate: false }), headers: {"AppId": "", "MasterKey": ""}, function (req, res) {
   console.log("testing")

});
```

Heroku logs

```
at=info method=POST path="/parse/index/testing" host=xxxxxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=..... fwd="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=41ms status=403 bytes=506
```

Comment: Can you run the `heroku logs` and see what happening

Comment: @abdulbarik I updated my question to include the logs

Comment: `statusCode=403` : you don’t have permission to access this resource

Comment: Yeah that's what I though, but how to I attach the keys to the request?

Comment: mean you want to attach in this route `app.post('/testing')`?

Comment: Yeah I have a very strong feeling I am getting denied access because I don't have the master key attached

Answer (score 1):

Try to attach you `master key` like this

```
app.post('/testing/masterkey/:masterkey', twilio.webhook({ validate: false }), function (req, res) {
   console.log("testing")
console.log(req.params.masterkey);
});
```

and request with this format

```
hostname/testing/masterkey/1234
```

**Edit**

Post call from Postman

[image]

Comment: I tired doing it like '/testing/Parse-Master-Key/xxxxxxxxxxxx' as well as the way you proposed, but I get the same error

Comment: are you able to get key or not ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Lie if you are expecting master key then you must be using it anywhere?

Comment: I found this useful link it says I must add the master key and app id in the request header, but not sure how to add the header in the code. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1657

Comment: Did you pass those keys in postman headers correctly? it's header part then you no need to give url parameters I am adding a screenshot of postman

Comment: Yeah I understand that part, but don't I need to add headers to the code?

Comment: You have to add headers every request time. Since Heroku expect it in that form

Comment: If I am not mistaken it would look something like this? `https://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/parse/index/testing/"Parse-Application-Id"="cccccccc"?"Parse-Master-Key"="xxxxxxxxx"`

Comment: Nope that will not gonna work you need to pass it with headers, why to go with request module to send post request

Comment: Oh ok, but it is still very nebulous on how to attach the header to the app.post line.

Comment: can you give me the code  from where you are requesting like you request from  postman

Comment: So I am working with twilio and all it is, is a link. I am using masked numbers so when a text goes through it calls the "testing" app.post function and performs some logic.

Comment: It's any tools to request to server?

Comment: That's the only way to request to the server

Comment: I updated my code to see if that would work. Can you do that?

Comment: Wait, if I am not wrong this is the heroku code where you are requesting from somewhere like postman or any other tools.
And if this is the your request code where you request to heroku then it's wrong way

Comment: I don't think so, when a text message is sent it uses the url in the image I provided couple comments back to try and send it to another user. Here is the tutorial for masked numbers https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/node/express#5